# Get IR stream from kinect

Tags: kinect, opencv, camera, ir, openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, everybody,

I need to capture the IR stream from IR camera of kinect and I have to use OpenCv Library for analizing it. Doing so, I built a subscriber at the topic `camera/ir/image_raw` of openni_launch and converted the captured image with `cv_bridge::toCvCopy(img, enc:MONO16)`, but as result I had a really very dark image (almost totally black).

I tried to used the IR camera with command:

```
rosrun image_view image_view image:=camera/ir/image_raw
```

and it works properly, so I ask to you: why it doesn't work in my source?

I write below my code:

```
ros::Subscriber subIRKinect = nh.subscribe("camera/ir/image_raw", 1000, getKinectIRImage);

void getKinectIRImage (const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr img)
{
    //image type mono16
    try
    {
        cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(img, enc::MONO16);
    }
    catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
    {
        ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
    }
 }
```

Thanks in advance everybody can help me!! ;)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11576/get-ir-stream-from-kinect/) by [Deby85](https://answers.ros.org/users/1233/deby85/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2011-10-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you Felix, I solved my problem simply using the the following command:

```
frame = img_bridge_.imgMsgToCv(img, "bgr8");
```

and now it works properly. :D

Hoping don't boring you, I have another question for you or everybody could help me: I installed ROS and openni_kinect on another computer exactly how I made previously on mine, but when I try to used the IR camera with command:

```
rosrun image_view image_view image:/camera/ir/image_raw
```

It returns me the following error:

```
Illegal Instruction
```

I've looked for a solution on the web, but I haven't found it. Could someone help me ??

Thanks in advance

---

Originally posted by [Deby85](https://answers.ros.org/users/1233/deby85/) with karma: 26 on 2011-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kadir Firat Uyanik](https://answers.ros.org/users/81/kadir-firat-uyanik/) on 2012-01-17**:
This illegal instruction was a bug a in opencv, and I heard that it's been fixed in the latest release. You may want to update your opencv package.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-11-08**:
For a new question open a new thread. This one sounds like you are using binaries that don't fit your system.